# Problems testing mix of ReceiverActor and ReceivePersistentActor with Akka.Persistence.TestKit

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-persistence

Net users,

right now I'am developing an application which uses Actors inheriting from ReceiveActor and Actors inheriting from ReceivePersistentActor.

I'am using Akka.Net, Akka.Persistence, Akka.TestKit version 1.3.1 and Akka.Persistence.TestKit version 1.2.3.43-beta.

Now I wrote a test class for a ReceiveActor with NUnit and the Akka.TestKit.NUnit worked fine. But we also use ReceivePersistentActors and there is apparently no support for them inside Akka.TestKit.

There is the Akka.Persistence.TestKit which aims for Akka.Net version 1.2.x support and also has dependencies regarding xunit (which I won't use - if possible)

So, my questions are:

- Is somewhere using the same setup, a mix of ReceiveActors and ReceivePersistentActors, and how do you test your application?
- Sometimes a ReceiveActor has childs of the type ReceivePersistentActor and vise versa. Is that a bad idea at all?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Akka.Persistence.TestKit is used solely to test custom event journal and snapshot store implementations for compatibility with Akka.Persistence protocols. It doesn't expose features to test persistent actors. There are no tools specific for Akka.net persistent actor testing at the moment.

Regarding your question about mixing standard and persistent actors - there is nothing wrong with that, however as I've said to test persistence features, you'll need some custom code.